# How to consolidate redundant data while retaining other unique info (see pic attached)?

Tags: excel, database, ms-access, organization, redundancy

[image: A sample similar to the kind of database I'm dealing with.]

What I'm trying to do is consolidate all of the redundant data into one, while retaining the unique information under John Smith and his unique ID.

Obviously only so much can be done about human data entry errors (VP/Vice President & X-Corp/X Corporation), but how can I consolidate all of this data to as little rows as possible without losing unique values?

How do I reduce the 4 "john.smith@company.com" emails into just one without affecting the subsequent data in other columns?  Or is it impossible because they contain different values in other fields?

Would it be better to approach this using a relational DB? If so then how should I construct?

Comment: One way of approaching within Access would be to write some VBA that takes the ID field, and then for each of the other fields, selects the data has the most values, and write all of this to a new table. However, if your data is such a mess, you will have to spend much time fixing this, and then work out a way to ensure that it doesn't get in such a mess in future.

Comment: Hi Applecore, thanks for the comment. The database is from my company, we are switching to a new software and need to scrub our old data in order to transfer. The DB I'm working with is a combined list of every single contact our company has from every location. Not much can be done about the data mess at this point, just trying to see if I can salvage and organize the majority of it. I'll give the Access method a shot, thanks.

Comment: You may also want to include an indicator of how frequent the "saved" data is. If it appears in 6 out of 7 cases, then it is probably good (although the 1 different piece of data may be newer and therefore correct). If it appears in 3 out of 7 cases, then it may not be as reliable, and may need manual reviewing.

Comment: The data I'm working with (contact info) is reliable and accurate, if that's what you are saying. The main issue is having 10+ rows for one contact which could be condensed into one by filling in blanks and reducing duplicates to one value

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the data you have? Why not just ensure you don't have any blank cells and then use the remove duplicate function to ensure you only have unique values within the email column?

Comment: The attached image is an example sample I made with similar format to the actual database I'm working with. The actual DB has around 50,000 rows and has massive amounts of the problem described.